# sqlAlchemy execute a select row for the second time, it return nothing

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I select and update a row data by `sqlalchemy`, when I execute the second time, `sqlalchemy` return None to me, why?

```
    db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8' % (db_user, db_pwd, db_host, db_name)
    engine = create_engine(db_connection, echo=False)
    session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)()
    while True:
        row = session.execute('select id, avi_id, address, code from job  where job_status = :job_status', {'job_status': 'created'}).fetchone()
        if row:
            session.execute('update job set job_status = :job_status where id = :job_id', {'job_status': "finished", 'job_id': row[0]})
            session.commit()
            time.sleep(3)
```

**Then I update `job_status` into `created` on mysql client:**

```
update job set job_status = "created" where job_status="finished"
```

Second loop(first code block), variable **row** is None, why?

Comment: The second update is the come from your first code block?

Comment: @lucumt yes, it's first code block.